# I made an executable using OCRA, but it doesnt find the chromedriver in other computers

Tags: ruby, watir, selenium-chromedriver, ocra

Hi I made a script to access a website using watir, then I used OCRA to create the exe file, but when I run the exe file in an other computer without ruby intalled, it doesnt find the chromedriver.exe.
I not allowed to install ruby on that computer, but I create the same path and copy the chromedriver like it was on my computer but not luck (if I change the location of the chromedriver on my computer it doesnt work too).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

> create the same path and copy the chromedriver like it was on my computer

Did you also add that directory to your PATH?

Or can you copy the missing program to a location in your PATH?

Comment: In the pc I test the .exe file, I went to "system", "change settings" and "Enviroment Variables",I add "Variable = Path" "Value = C:\Ruby193\bin" (the same as the pc where I create the script).

Comment: is that the PATH you mean? Im new in to programming so I dont know many of this things

Comment: Yes, I mean the PATH. But not to add ruby-path (that must be done already), but the path to the chromedriver.exe. If the chromedriver.exe is not in the PATH, then ruby will not find it - as far as I now, chromedriver.exe isn't part of Watir, but part of chrome (or another related library).

Comment: Do you know where can I find this PATH?

Comment: See http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm (maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows helps also a bit)

Comment: I tried that but didn't work, I change the script to use Firefox, I don't have problems with drivers but now I have problems downloading files, I cann't skip the download popup